# How to understand the end-points in Reactjs for fetching data from server

Tags: reactjs, endpoint

I am new in Reactjs for fetching api's.End point share me backend developer from the server 192.34.55.55:4000 show me many end points i cannot understand it properly,i fetch one for signin request with token,problem show me when i  signin redirect to private page like user ,now backend developer say me i secure api with token handle request but show me error 400 bad request error etc.please tell me how i can handle end points,i search on internet many times but cannot find the right answer that fullfill my requirments.

tell me how endpoints works and how i fetch it in reactJs?

```
Available routes
      session_path  POST    /api/sign_in             FuelUpWeb.SessionController :sign_in
   technology_path  GET     /api/technologies        FuelUpWeb.TechnologyController :index
   technology_path  GET     /api/technologies/:id    FuelUpWeb.TechnologyController :show
   technology_path  POST    /api/technologies        FuelUpWeb.TechnologyController :create
   technology_path  PATCH   /api/technologies/:id    FuelUpWeb.TechnologyController :update
                    PUT     /api/technologies/:id    FuelUpWeb.TechnologyController :update
   technology_path  DELETE  /api/technologies/:id    FuelUpWeb.TechnologyController :delete
        sport_path  GET     /api/sports              FuelUpWeb.SportController :index
        sport_path  GET     /api/sports/:id          FuelUpWeb.SportController :show
        sport_path  POST    /api/sports              FuelUpWeb.SportController :create
        sport_path  PATCH   /api/sports/:id          FuelUpWeb.SportController :update
                    PUT     /api/sports/:id          FuelUpWeb.SportController :update
        sport_path  DELETE  /api/sports/:id          FuelUpWeb.SportController :delete
     national_path  GET     /api/nationals           FuelUpWeb.NationalController :index
     national_path  GET     /api/nationals/:id       FuelUpWeb.NationalController :show
     national_path  POST    /api/nationals           FuelUpWeb.NationalController :create
     national_path  PATCH   /api/nationals/:id       FuelUpWeb.NationalController :update
                    PUT     /api/nationals/:id       FuelUpWeb.NationalController :update
     national_path  DELETE  /api/nationals/:id       FuelUpWeb.NationalController :delete
international_path  GET     /api/internationals      FuelUpWeb.InternationalController :index
international_path  GET     /api/internationals/:id  FuelUpWeb.InternationalController :show
international_path  POST    /api/internationals      FuelUpWeb.InternationalController :create
international_path  PATCH   /api/internationals/:id  FuelUpWeb.InternationalController :update
                    PUT     /api/internationals/:id  FuelUpWeb.InternationalController :update
international_path  DELETE  /api/internationals/:id  FuelUpWeb.InternationalController :delete
```

Comment: Hello, you need to authenticate the user to access private content. Please look at the following [article](https://vladimirponomarev.com/blog/authentication-in-react-apps-jwt). You will need a similar strategy as shown in the client-side section.

Comment: @eenagy  i read it,i authenticate it using token but in private page how i handle and fetch data because shoe me this type of api  /api/technologies/:id  so how i fech it,please share me any link for proper understanding about thank you

Comment: you need to pass the token to every method with fetch, except `/api/signin`
Try to test your api with `curl` or `postman` first, the API developer should provide you with relevant information

Comment: show me invalid token in postman.when i try to acces api

Comment: is it the same, if you get a new token via postman signin?

Comment: yeah same message show me

Comment: i pass token in headers:{  'Authorization':localStorge.token } in fetch method,but a problem is that i cannot understand how display data from this type of api's ./api/technologies/:id  how to handle :id i cannot understand how i write this id also confuse

Comment: Your question is too broad, other user will flag your question later on.
Please look at [this article understanding rest apis](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/)

And use [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) for these discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196233/discussion-between-kashif-and-eenagy).